# Query Builder for AW API?

Tags: google-ads-api, looker-studio, google-ads-script

I'm trying to find all my accounts with cost == 0.

```
 var query =
   'SELECT AccountDescriptiveName, Cost FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING LAST_7_DAYS WHERE Cost > 0';
 var recommendationResult = AdsApp.search(query, { apiVersion: 'v8' });
```

But I get this exception:

> Exception: Could not identify resource for search query "SELECT
> AccountDescriptiveName, Cost FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING
> LAST_7_DAYS WHERE Metric.Cost == 0". Double-check your FROM clause.
> (file Code.gs, line 18)

I wanted to build it from scratch using the [Query Builder](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v8/account_budget_proposal_query_builder) but I haven't found ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT report (AW API) or it GA API equivalent.

Also, using the GAds connector to data studio. Is there a way to fetch the query behind some table?

[image]

Comment: Would it be a option to tranfer the Google Ads data to BigQuery once a day? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` only gives you metrics for one single account, so it's not going to be appropriate for your use case. Generally there's no way to query multiple accounts at once in neither the Adwords API nor the Ads API.

If this is specifically about Data Studio and you have less than 50 accounts, then you can just add them all as a single data source. If there's more, you could set up a BigQuery transfer service as suggested by @Samuel (assuming all the accounts are under the same manager account), create a `UNION ALL` view of all the resulting `Customer_<customer_id>`  tables and create a Data Studio source connected to that view.

Comment: Say I have a dashboard based on GAds connector.
Is there any way to fetch the GAQL or AWQL query behind this dashboard?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the GAds connector for DS, so I can't say for sure. I haven't seen such a feature, though.